# How do I specify a Sinon.JS spy function as part of a class definition?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing a Backbone.js app using Require.js and Backbone.Marionette and testing it using Mocha with Chai, Sinon, and Sinon-Chai.  I've been generally using [Jarrod Overson's Backbone Marionette with Require.JS TODO sample](https://github.com/jsoverson/todomvc/tree/master/labs/dependency-examples/backbone_marionette_require) as a reference for application structure and [Jim Newbery's posts on testing Backbone apps](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html) as a reference for unit testing.

My problem is trying to test adding a [Marionette ItemView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md) to a [Marionette Application object](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md).  I figured the best way to test that the ItemView is added is watch for its `render()` method to be called.  Since Marionette provides a default `render()` implementation, I thought it best to just use a Sinon spy for the `onRender()` callback.

I used [Squire.JS](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js) to return a stub class for my ItemView as shown below:

```
define(['Squire', 'backbone.marionette'], function(Squire, Marionette) {
    describe('App', function() {

        var testContext;

        beforeEach(function(done) {
            testContext = {};

            testContext.injector = new Squire();

            testContext.renderSpy = sinon.spy();

            testContext.injector.mock('app/views/Header', function() {
                var stub_template_html = "<div></div>";
                var HeaderStub = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
                    template: function(serialized_model) {
                        return _.template(stub_template_html);
                    }
                });
                return HeaderStub;
            });

            testContext.injector.require(['app/app'], function(app) {
                testContext.app = app;
                done();
            });
        });

        it ('Should add a Header view to the \'header\' region', function() {
            testContext.app.start();
            expect(testContext.renderSpy).to.be.called();
        });
```

When I run Mocha via Chrome, I get the error I expect: "expected spy to have been called at least once, but it was never called."  However, if I specify the Sinon spy function as the `onRender()` callback, as shown below

```
var HeaderStub = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // ...
    onRender: testContext.renderSpy
});
```

I get an error stating that the `called()` method is not a function.

Is there a way to specify a Sinon spy function as a method in a class definition?  Alternatively, is there a better way to test this code?  I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so this may be a more general problem rather than a Sinon-specific problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what assertion library you are using, but to check if a function you spy on with sinon was called, you have to check the `called` property of the spy. See http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies

> **spy.called**
>
> true if the spy was called at least once

So your assertion should look like this:

```
expect(testContext.renderSpy).to.be(true);
```

Comment: I'm using [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) for my assertion library and the [Sinon-Chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) plug-in to provide consistent assertions.  I think my syntax is correct, but I'll give your suggestion a try to see if that makes a difference.  Thanks.

Comment: You were right.  I was using the wrong syntax. `called` is a property, not a function.  You can either use `expect(testContext.renderSpy.called).to.be.true` (native Chai) or `expect(testContext.renderSpy).to.be.called` (Sinon-Chai).  Note the lack of parentheses at the end of the statement.